# Auto populate cells on a different sheet based on user input pop-up box

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet with two sheets titled Finance and Invoice.
I want the Finance page to have cells which I would fill out by typing in the cells.
I want the Invoice page to be auto-populated from the information in the Finance sheet.

I want the code to populate cells on the Invoice sheet from the cells on the Finance sheet, based on cells a few spaces away from a cell that is specified by a user typing in a letter which is associated with a cell in column A of the Finance sheet.

How do I get the Finance range (which will be copied by the code) to reference a cell that is a few over from a user-input cell in a row in column A?

**Invoice Sheet**
[image: Photo of the Invoice Sheet]

**Finance Sheet**
[image: Photo of the Finance Sheet]

In the top part of the code, I am copying information from cells in the Finance sheet into the Invoice sheet. The code creates a pop-up box where the user is supposed to write in a letter 'A-Z' , where 'A-Z' are written in cells A 2-27 on the Finance sheet.

The code is copying cells from the Finance sheet into the Invoice sheet.

I want a pop-up box that asks a user for a letter, they type in a letter 'A-Z'- I'll call it 'A' (this would be in cell B2 on the Finance sheet).
The code will then copy the cell 1 to the right of cell B2 on the Finance sheet and paste it into cell D3 on the Invoice sheet.

I think I need to edit the `Sheets("Finance").Range"B2")` portion of the code.

```vb
Sub Macro2()

    'Ask user for input
    userinput = InputBox("Type Associated Letter corresponding to Desired Invoice Population:")
    'Copy Name
    Sheets("Finance").Range("B2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D3")
    'Copy Email
    Sheets("Finance").Range("C2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D4")
    'Copy Adress
    Sheets("Finance").Range("D2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D5")
    'Copy Date
    Sheets("Finance").Range("E2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("B8")
    'Copy Amount Owed
    Sheets("Finance").Range("I2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D8")
```

Comment: You can use `Application.Match()` to locate the required row on the finance sheet, then use that information to copy over the cells from that row to the invoice sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Match Values in Column (`Application.Match`)

```vb
Sub InvoiceWriter()

    ' Define constants.
 
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Invoice Writer"
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Finance"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Invoice"

    Dim srcCols() As Variant, dstCells() As Variant
    ' Name, Email, Address, Date, Owed
    srcCols = Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "I")
    dstCells = Array("D3", "D4", "D5", "B8", "D8")

    ' Input.

    Dim UserInput As String: UserInput = InputBox("Type Associated Letter " _
        & "corresponding to Desired Invoice Population:", PROC_TITLE)

    If Len(UserInput) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the Source Input range.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(slCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Retrieve the Source User Input row index.
    
    Dim srIndex As Variant: srIndex = Application.Match(UserInput, srg, 0)
    
    If IsError(srIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Could not find '" & UserInput & "'.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    srIndex = srIndex + srg.Row - 1 ' convert range row to worksheet row
    
    ' Write the values from the Source to the Destination cells.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(srcCols) To UBound(srcCols)
        dws.Range(dstCells(n)).Value = sws.Cells(srIndex, srcCols(n)).Value
    Next n
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Invoice populated.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```